# Parts of mini page are not placed properly

Tags: spacing, minipage

Question:

Right now i am working in mini page, the problem is components of mini page are not placed at good place. I want to reduce the space between them and both start from the same line from top (i mean horizontally in same line)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=0.5in,hmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,cancel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
        [140,black 
        [2]
        [70
        [2] 
        [35
        [5]
        [7]
        ]       
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{minipage}
%\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.55\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
    140 &= 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 7&\\
    &= 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference point for a `forest` is at the bottom. You can make it at the top so it aligns with a standard line of text with `\adjustbox` and `valign=t`. For the equation use `aligned`.

Finally, decide for the spacing between the objects, here `\quad` is used.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
    [140,black
      [2]
      [70
        [2]
        [35
          [5]
          [7]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
}% end of adjustbox (the % next to the brace is important
\qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
  140 &= 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 7&\\
      &= 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `baseline` option, you can vertically align the two parts so that the two instances of 140 are at the same height.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} baseline, for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
  [140,black
    [2]
    [70
      [2]
      [35
        [5]
        [7]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}\qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
  140 &= 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 7&\\
      &= 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For vertical centering,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=c}
\begin{forest} baseline=center, for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
  [140,black
    [2]
    [70
      [2]
      [35
        [5]
        [7]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}\qquad
$\begin{aligned}
  140 &= 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 7&\\
      &= 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

If you want to set this inside a math display, omit the `$` characters and exploit `gathered`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{forest} baseline=center, for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt}
  [140,black
    [2]
    [70
      [2]
      [35
        [5]
        [7]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{gathered}\qquad
\begin{aligned}
  140 &= 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 7&\\
      &= 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pleased to know new things. one request, Is it possible to place right part in the middle? i am asking Just for getting additional information.

Comment: @Sandy In the middle of what?

Comment: i mean middle of first part, slightly below from its original position

Comment: @Sandy Do you mean that you want the two instances of 140 being aligned?

Comment: Keep left part (tree) as it is. I don't want to move it.  I am asking that how the equations part can we push vertically below exact in the middle of the tree.

Comment: @Sandy Added more options

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=0.5in,hmargin=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,cancel} 
\usepackage{array,booktabs} 
\usepackage{forest} 
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{varwidth}[t]{.45\textwidth} \vspace{0pt}
\begin{forest} for tree={circle,draw, l sep=10pt} [140,black [2] [70 
    [2] [35 [5] [7] ]
    ] ] 
\end{forest} 
\end{varwidth} 
%\hfill 
\begin{varwidth}[t]{.55\textwidth} \vspace{0pt}
$ 140 = 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 7 = 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 $
\end{varwidth} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice it works. One question how can i place second component in the middle?

Comment: Put it between the two `varwidth` without an empty line!